# Replace sequences between files using Biopython

Tags: python, replace, sequence, biopython, fasta

I have two protein sequences FASTA files:

nsp.fasta --> original file

wsp.fasta --> output file from a signal peptide predictor tool, which returned the proteins in nsp.fasta with the signal stripped.

For example:

record in nsp.fasta:

```
>gi|564250271|ref|XP_006264203.1| PREDICTED: apolipoprotein D [Alligator mississippiensis]
MRGMLALLAALLGLLGLVEGQTFHMGQCPNPPVQEDFDPSKYLGKWYEIEKLPSGFEQER
CVQANYSLKANGKIKVLTKMVRSAQHLTCLQHRMMLLVSSPVMPASPYWVVATDYENYAL
VYSCTSFFWLFHVDYAWIRSRTPQLHPETVEHLKSVLRSYRIQTGMMLPTDQMNCPSDM
```

record in wsp.fasta:

```
>gi|564250271|ref|XP|006264203.1|  PREDICTED: apolipoprotein D [Alligator mississippiensis]; MatureChain: 21-179
QTFHMGQCPNPPVQEDFDPSKYLGKWYEIEKLPSGFEQERCVQANYSLKANGKIKVLTKM
VRSAQHLTCLQHRMMLLVSSPVMPASPYWVVATDYENYALVYSCTSFFWLFHVDYAWIRS
RTPQLHPETVEHLKSVLRSYRIQTGMMLPTDQMNCPSDM
```

However, not all the proteins in nsp.fasta contained a signal peptide, so wsp.fasta is a subset of the proteins in nsp.fasta that contains the signal. What I need is a unique file that contains all the protein records, both proteins with no signal peptide found and the mature chains with the signal peptide stripped.

I have tried the following:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

file1 = SeqIO.parse(r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\nsp.fasta", "fasta")

file2 = SeqIO.parse(r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\wsp.fasta", "fasta")

for seq1 in file1:
    for seq2 in file2:
        if seq2.id == seq1.id:
            seq1.seq = seq2.seq
            SeqIO.write(seq1, r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\nuevsp.fasta", "fasta")
```

But there's no output at all. I have tried putting the SeqIO.write out of the loops, and it returns a blank file. What am I doing wrong? There already exist any method to merge two files or to replace sequences in one file with sequences in other file?

Thank you in advance!!

Sergio

Edited code, I added an elif clause in an attempt to also add the records in nsp.fasta that doesn't match wsp.fasta, but it doesn't work:

```
to_write = []

for seq1 in SeqIO.parse(r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\nsp.txt", "fasta"):
    for seq2 in SeqIO.parse(r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\wsp.txt", "fasta"):
        if seq1.id == seq2.id:
            seq1.seq = seq2.seq
            to_write.append(seq1)
        elif seq1.id != seq2.id:
            to_write.append(seq1)

SeqIO.write(to_write, r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\nuevsp.txt", "fasta")
```

Comment: "gi|564250271|ref|XP|006264203.1|" is different to "gi|564250271|ref|XP_006264203.1|" .... "XP|0" and "XP_0" ?

Comment: Yeah that was one of the typo errors I commented bellow. I already corrected it, but thank you anyway!!

Comment: you don't forget to accept the @iayork answer and upvoting ;-)

Comment: Oh sorry I'm new here and still don't control that kind of things hahaha I already upvoted and accepted it, hadn't realised I had to activate the green tick icon. Thank you for the reminder!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written it, every time you write a new sequence, you're overwriting the previous one.  Try storing your records in a list and then writing out the list when the loop is completed.

```
to_write = []
for seq1 in SeqIO.parse(r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\nsp.fasta", "fasta"):
    for seq2 in SeqIO.parse(r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\wsp.fasta", "fasta"):
        if seq2.id == seq1.id:
            seq1.seq = seq2.seq
            to_write.append(seq1)
SeqIO.write(to_write, r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\nuevsp.fasta", "fasta")
```

Edit to suggest another approach using list comprehensions:

```
ids_to_save = [x.id for x in SeqIO.parse(r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\nsp.fasta", "fasta")]
records_to_save = [x for x in SeqIO.parse(r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\wsp.fasta", "fasta") if (x.id in ids_to_save)]
SeqIO.write(records_to_save, r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\nuevsp.fasta", "fasta")
```

Edit to address the "add the records in nsp.fasta that doesn't match wsp.fasta" need - general approach, not necessarily exact code:

```
ids_not_wanted = [x.id for x in SeqIO.parse(r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\wsp.fasta", "fasta")]
records_to_save_2 = [x for x in SeqIO.parse(r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\wsp.fasta", "fasta") if (x.id not in ids_not_wanted)]

records_to_save.append(records_to_save_2)
# If duplicate records are a problem, eliminate them using "set"
records_to_save = list(set(records_to_save))
SeqIO.write(records_to_save, r"c:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\nuevsp.fasta", "fasta")
```

Comment: Thanks for your correction! Now the code effectively returns a valid output, but not as desired, so there must be some error in the logic of my loops. Some records are stored and some others not, even if they should. As I understand my code, for every record in the first file, iterate over every record in the second file, and if the ids are the same, substitute the sequence and store it in the list. Am I right? Does anybody notice something wrong in that reasoning? Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you again! Actually I solved the problem I was referring to just by fixing some typo errors in the ids that was causing the unexpected mismatches. What I need now is to include also the records in nsp.fasta that doesn't exist in wsp.fasta. I have tried adding and elif (see my edited initial post), but it returns the same records multiple times. Your alternative solution works nicely as your previous approach, but doesn't address this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is a perfect solution. I really appreciate your effort!!